# updating xml using xpath in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a xml ; I need to update some values dynamically.

For Ex :

```
 <School>
  <class name=1>
   <students>10</students>
   <teacher>3</teacher>
  </class>
  <class name=2>
   <students>102</students>
   <teacher>13</teacher>
  </class>
</School>
```

Where in other xml:

i will have xpath and corresponding value
For eg :

```
 <data>
  <path>/school/class['name' = 1]/students</path><value>20</value>
 </data>
```

so when i query thru xslt

Default xml will be fetched and data related xml will also be fetched  and need to replace the corresponding values.

Is it possible to do thru xslt ..?

Comment: Dynamic XPath expression parsing and evaluation isn't possible either in XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0. It most likely will be possible in XSLT 3.0. Until then, it is better to change the unrealistic design/requirement.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT will transform XML documents to another form (including another XML document).  This is typically how you would do this, by creating a new output file that has some transformation happening.  Then you can remove the old file and replace with the new one.

Edit:
Upon re-reading your post, I think you also are asking if you can process two XML documents as input to the XSLT and the answer is yes, you can.  Take a look at the "document()" function.

Answer (score 0):

To start, a couple of comments:

1. Your XML isn't well formed (attribute values should be enclosed in quotes)
2. The XPath expression `/school/class['name' = 1]/students` will probably not do what you expect;) ... The predicate `'name' = 1` compares the string `'name'` with the integer `1` and returns false, meaning that your expression will always return an empty node set. To select the class which name attribute is 1, you'd rather write: `/school/class[@name = 1]/students`

Back to your question!

With standard XSLT 1 or 2 you cannot execute dynamic XPath expressions. This should be possible with XSLT 3.0 and this may be possible using proprietary extensions (depending on your processor).

A language such as XQuery (with its update facilities) could be a better fit (if you can bend your XPath expressions to be conform XQuery of course).

If you still need to use XSLT, the way I usually perform this kind of tasks is by generating a XSLT transformation as a first step and executing it as a second step.

The first step can itself be an XSLT transformation and it will copy your XPath expressions within the XSLT transformation that is being generated. When the second step is run, these XPath expressions are just plain static XPath expressions...